# Laravel API rate limiter for specific method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Is there any way to apply rate limit (throttle) for specific method like **POST**, **PUT** to prevent multiple api hitting within seconds

I tried to apply limit for whole api in **/app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
    ],
    'api' => [
      'throttle:1,0.008', <<--- its prevent all api within 0.48 sec         
    ],
];
```

**Problem :**

we need to prevent only selected **methods**.

Answer (score 2):

There are number of ways to do it,  You can create another middleware which you can use and group the routes you want to apply custom throttle.

Additionally, you can straightly apply the throttle when defining a route

```
Route::post('/wiggle', function () {
    //
})->middleware(['auth:api','throttle:1,0.008']);
```

or

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api','throttle:1,0.008'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('wiggle', [YourClass::class, 'wiggle'])->name('wiggle');
});
```

Comment: we know this methods to apply limit. but question is that, How to apply API limit for specific methods

Comment: I already gave you an example lol, define the throttle middleware on the routes method you want to apply a limiter by either grouping them or individually applying a middleware for each

Comment: Means that, there is no option to apply limter for POST method globally

Comment: you can create your own middleware that checks the request method and applies a throttle which you can then add inside ```api``` ```$middlewareGroups```.

Comment: ok i will try this one

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple ways to make rate limit in Laravel.

One of ways is Middleware. silver already describe the way.

Second way is using `Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter` **(Laravel 8 or higher)**

For example, if you want to send email verification messages with rate limit 1 message per 60 seconds.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;

class EmailVerificationController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $email = $request->input('email');

        $resendSmsTimeoutSecs = 60;
        $rateLimiterKey = 'email-verification:' . $email;
        RateLimiter::attempt($rateLimiterKey, 1,
            function () use ($user) {
                $user->sendEmailVerification();
            },
            $resendSmsTimeoutSecs
        );

        return response()->json([
            'resend_timeout' => RateLimiter::availableIn($rateLimiterKey)
        ]);
    }
}
```

[About `RateLimiter`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/rate-limiting)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use the RateLimiter is as follows:

```
$executed = RateLimiter::attempt('send-message',2,function(){});
if($executed){
    return response()->json([
       'test' => 'test success'
    ]);
}else{
   return response()->json('Too many attempts!');
}
```

**OR**

```
$executed = RateLimiter::attempt('send-message',2,function(){
   return response()->json([
       'test' => 'test success'
    ]);
});
if(!$executed){
   return response()->json('Too many attempts!');
}
return $executed;
```

Reference [Laravel Rate Limiting docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/rate-limiting)